# Split a div into four separate divs

Tags: html, css

[image: squares in square]
<sub>(source: [kheper.net](http://www.kheper.net/topics/civilization/four.gif))</sub>

The effect I'm going for is the whole square being one div, with each square being a smaller div within the bigger div, correctly aligned, to take up the entire viewport.

Similar to [montere.it](https://www.montere.it/?lang=en) minus the JavaScript.

I've tried to highlight the problematic bits of code, the corresponding CSS isn't formatting correctly but I've linked a JS bin below.
Apologies if my code is spaghetti code, it's less my code and more a copy and paste session gone wild.

```css
#bodyHobbies {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.intbox1 {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009900;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.intbox2 {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #990000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.intbox3 {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.intbox4 {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #990000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="bodyHobbies">
    <div class="intbox1">
        <p>1</p>
        <img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox2">
        <p>2</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox3">
        <p>3</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox4">
        <p>4</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/heyibe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Look for CSS frameworks. Would reduce a lot of effort

Comment: I think Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644245/divide-a-div-into-four-equal-parts-filling-the-viewport-with-a-fixed-nav-bar

Comment: It's funny, I'm doing a site based on Montere.it too. They created their entire site with bootstrap. Achieving this with bootstrap is cake. Consider using it for yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added `display: inline-table` to you `#bodyHobbies` and added a common class to the intbox divs. Removed the individual intbox stylings related to width and heights.

```css
#bodyHobbies {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-table;
}

.intbox {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.intbox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.intbox1 {
  background-color:#009900;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;

}

.intbox2 {
  background-color:#990000;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.intbox3 {
  background-color:#000000;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.intbox4 {
  background-color:#933230;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyHobbies">
    <div class="intbox intbox1"><p>1</p>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/700/sports/1/" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox intbox2"><p>2</p>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/700/sports/1/" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox intbox3"><p>3</p>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/700/sports/1/" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox intbox4"><p>4</p>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/700/sports/1/" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i add an image it spills out of the divs

Comment: See the new changes just added ```img``` style ```width: 100%;``` You can make additional changes as per your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

you can done that using **css3 flexbox** concept

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
img{
  width:100%;
  }
#bodyHobbies{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
.item{
  flex-basis:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="bodyHobbies">
    <div class="intbox1 item"><p>1</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqmw.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox2  item"><p>2</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqmw.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox3 item"><p>3</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqmw.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="intbox4 item"><p>4</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqmw.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="bodyHobbies">
    <div class="box">
        <p>1</p>
        <img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>2</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>3</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>4</p>
        <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .box{width:calc(50% - 2px); margin:2px; float:left; min-height:100px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="bodyHobbies">
<div class="intbox1"><p>1</p>
  <img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="intbox2"><p>2</p>
  <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="intbox3"><p>3</p>
  <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="intbox4"><p>4</p>
  <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #bodyHobbies div{
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At `css` use `vw`, `vh` units to set `body`, parent element `width`, `height` to `100vw`, `100vh`. Set `[class=^"int"]` selector `position` to `absolute`. Set element `left` and `top` properties corresponding to the four positions within the viewport using `:nth-of-type()` pseudo class. `left:0vw`, `top:0vh`; `left:50vw`, `top:0vh`; `left:0vw`,  `top:50vh`, `left:50vw`, `top:50vh`.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#bodyHobbies {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid sienna;
}
[class^="int"] {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}
[class^="int"]:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0vw;
  top: 0vw;
  background: blue;
}
[class^="int"]:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50vw;
  top: 0vh;
  background: green
}
[class^="int"]:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0vw;
  top: 50vh;
  background: red;
}
[class^="int"]:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyHobbies">
  <div class="intbox1">
    <p>1</p>
    <img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" alt="foobar1" />
  </div>
  <div class="intbox2">
    <p>2</p>
    <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" alt="foobar2" />
  </div>
  <div class="intbox3">
    <p>3</p>
    <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" alt="foobar3" />
  </div>
  <div class="intbox4">
    <p>4</p>
    <img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" alt="foobar4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69zkbjgw/